# JS file not working in webhost, but works on my local xampp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I call the index.js it doesn't work in my webhost server and the cdn too but works  perfectly on my Local xampp server .

```
    <?php 
    /* Main page with two forms: sign up and log in */
    require 'db.php';
    session_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
    <?php include 'css/css.html'; ?>
    </head>

    <?php 
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { //user logging in

        require 'login.php';

    }

    elseif (isset($_POST['register'])) { //user registering

        require 'register.php';

    }
    }
    ?>
    <body>
    <div class="form">

      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#login">Log in</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">

         <div id="login">   
          <h1>Welcome to </h1>

          <form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

            <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" required autocomplete="off" 
 name="email"/>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password" required autocomplete="off"         
    name="password"/>
          </div>

          <p class="forgot"><a href="forgot.php">Forgot Password?</a></p>

          <button class="button button-block" name="login" />Log 
In</button>

          </form>

        </div>

        <div id="signup">   
          <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

          <form action="index.php" method="post" id="form1" 
    autocomplete="off">

          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                First Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" 
 name='firstname' id="txtNumeric" />
             </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text"required autocomplete="off" 
 name='lastname' 
    id="txtNumeric" />
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Contact number<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="number"required autocomplete="off" 
 name='contact' 
    onclick="return AllowSingleSpaceNotInFirstAndLast();" />
          </div>


          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off" name='email' 
    onclick="return AllowSingleSpaceNotInFirstAndLast();" />
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off" 
    name='password'/>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="button button-block" 
  name="register" 
    onclick="return validates()" />Register</button>

          </form>

        </div>  

      </div><!-- tab-content -->

    </div> <!-- /form -->
    <script 

 src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'> 
    </script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function validates(){

    $(function() {

    $('#txtNumeric').keydown(function (e) {

    if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {

      e.preventDefault();

    } else {

      var key = e.keyCode;

      if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key 
 <= 
    40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {

        e.preventDefault();

      }

      }

     });

    });

    function AllowSingleSpaceNotInFirstAndLast() {
        var obj = document.getElementById('TextBox1');
        obj.value = obj.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        var CharArray = obj.value.split(" ");
        if (CharArray.length > 2) {
            alert("User name NOT VALID");
            return false;
        }[enter image description here][1]
        else {
            alert("User name VALID");
        }
        return true;
    }

    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem here is I cannot run the code properly in my webhost.  My code works fine on local xampp server. I also edited the DB user, DB name etc but it doesn't help. can anyone help me ?

Thank you!

*PS. I am new to stackoverflow. sorry for my bad formatting*

Comment: Please indent your code properly for better readability .

Comment: It could be a number of things. Do you have access to your servers error logs? Can you run other any php on your server? Does your sever support PHP?

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: it is just a free host. 000webhost.com btw. Yes I can run my other php file here. This is a online shop, for example I can add products and put it in the database of webhost and can display too in browser.

Comment: No error @SambhajiKatrajkar If you can see the picture I uploaded here. I cannot click the sign up button. And I try to erase the js file on my local xampp, I got the same problem in webhost.

Comment: defense tomorrow :( still not working :((((

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your path of files you should check your path of file 
or may be you had not uploaded your all files with proper code on server.

Replace this code

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>/js/index.js"></script>
```